# error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.ColorPropConverter

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Every time I try to run my react native project using `react-native run-android`, it throws me the following error

```
\RenderableView.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ColorPropConverter;
\Documents\GitHubProjects\node_modules\react-native-svg\android\src\main\java\com\horcrux\svg\RenderableView.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ColorPropConverter;
                                ^
  symbol:   class ColorPropConverter
  location: package com.facebook.react.bridge
\Documents\GitHubProjects\node_modules\react-native-svg\android\src\main\java\com\horcrux\svg\SvgView.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ColorPropConverter;
                                ^
  symbol:   class ColorPropConverter
  location: package com.facebook.react.bridge
\Documents\GitHubProjects\node_modules\react-native-svg\android\src\main\java\com\horcrux\svg\RenderableView.java:480: error: cannot find symbol
                      color = ColorPropConverter.getColor(colors.getMap(1), getContext());
                              ^
  symbol:   variable ColorPropConverter
  location: class RenderableView
\Documents\GitHubProjects\node_modules\react-native-svg\android\src\main\java\com\horcrux\svg\SvgView.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
          mTintColor = ColorPropConverter.getColor(tintColor.asMap(), getContext());
                       ^
  symbol:   variable ColorPropConverter
  location: class SvgView
4 errors
```

Keep in mind this was when I cloned a repository from GitHub and after running `npm install`.

Probably I should mention too there's a `react-native+0.62.2.patch` file in the project that I don't remember adding, so I don't know if that has something to do with it.

My guess is that the `ColorPropConverter` file has gone missing...if so, why it got deleted and how can I restore it? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yarn add react-native-svg@12.1.0
it's help me

because version 12.3.0(latest) is not suit for react-native 0.62